# guestmount inside a lxd container gives an "Operation not permitted" error

Tags: mount, lxc, lxd, fuse

I've created a qcow2 disk (using qemu-img) inside an ubuntu 16.04 lxd container (created via this command: lxc launch images:ubuntu/xenial/amd64 mycont). I've partitioned it and formated it with guestfish without trouble. But when I want to mount it to fill it with files I execute this command...:

*guestmount -a disk.qcow2 -m /dev/sda1 /path/mount/point*

...and I get this error:

*fusermount : mount failed : Operation not permitted

libguestfs : error : fuser_mount : /path/mount/point : Operation not permitted*

The same command on a real Ubuntu works well. In fact, the "mount" command inside guestfish works well too. I'm turning crazy because I can't find any solution to this!

Thans a lot!

Comment: Have you tried the command with `sudo`?

Comment: I'm root inside the container

Comment: Something to do with AppArmor maybe?  There are some possible things to try mentioned here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/docker-user/qwudZkw4WH4

Comment: Thanks. I've executed *lxc config set mycontainer raw.lxc lxc.aa_profile=unconfined* but I still get the same error .                             I've also disabled AppArmor from host machine but with no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into similar problem that I needed fuse for sshfs to function inside lxd guest. LXD developer (stgraber) replied to a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxd/+bug/1583765/comments/2) that it's the ubuntu kernel that's restricting the container mounts.

Bug report links to this article: [Container Mounts in Ubuntu 16.04](http://blog.forshee.me/2016/02/container-mounts-in-ubuntu-1604.html).

In short you need at least kernel 4.4.0-6.21.
On the lxd host enable required kernel modules for user namespace
For fuse it is

```
# fuse
echo Y | sudo tee /sys/module/fuse/parameters/userns_mounts
# ext4 (see article for more information, not needed for sshfs)
#echo Y | sudo tee /sys/module/ext4/parameters/userns_mounts
```

Then create a profile that creates required devices for udev and aa_profile:

```
 lxc profile create nsmount  
 lxc profile set nsmount raw.lxc lxc.aa_profile=unconfined
 # expose these devices to the container  
 lxc profile device add nsmount fuse unix-char path=/dev/fuse  
 #lxc profile device add nsmount loop0 unix-block path=/dev/loop0
```

If you are creating a new container use '-p' flags:

```
lxc launch ubuntu MyNewContainer -p default -p nsmount
```

If you have existing container use apply:

```
lxc profile apply MyExistingContainer default,nsmount
```

Remember to list all applied profiles if you have other special profiles.