# system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs image using "squashfs - mount failed

Tags: mount, 19.10, snap, lxc

I'm attempting to install PowerShell on my Ubuntu instance using `snap`, but it generates an error:

```
# sudo snap install powershell --classic
error: system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs image using "squashfs": mount:
       /tmp/sanity-mountpoint-072786794: mount failed: Operation not permitted.
```

I'm running Ubuntu Eoan in a LXC container on a Turris Omnia router:

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.10
Release:    19.10
Codename:   eoan

# uname -m
armv7l

# snap --version
snap    2.42.1+19.10
snapd   2.42.1+19.10
series  16
ubuntu  19.10
kernel  4.14.162
```

I'm able to create a directory in `/tmp`.

[This posting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/858963/guestmount-inside-a-lxd-container-gives-an-operation-not-permitted-error) suggests that I need at least kernel 4.4.0-6.21; I have 4.14.162.

Why is this failing?

Comment: I'm having the same issue running LXC under Arch with kernel 5.8.9. [This Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61023131) might be relevant, but I haven't looked into it yet. In the end I stopped troubleshooting this because running snaps inside an LXC container seems a bit... excessive.

Comment: Try `sudo apt install fuse squashfuse` https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-on-fedora

Comment: install fuse and squashfuse fixed this for me. Might be a good idea to add it as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am reposting the answer to make it more visible.
Credit to @user.dz

`sudo apt install fuse squashfuse` works.

Comment: this didn't work for me