# Snap gives wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop23 eror

Tags: 20.04, mount, snap, squashfs

```
$ sudo snap remove audacity
error: system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs image using "squashfs": mount:
       /tmp/sanity-mountpoint-881202120: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop23,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

I've removed and installed `snap`
I've checked all other similar question but most of them doesn't apply `dev/loop`mounts. Since it's getting mounted by snap I don't know how to interfere

Two answers suggested me to install but squashfuse is already newest version.

```
r@ig:~$ sudo apt-get install libsquashfuse0 squashfuse fuse 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
fuse is already the newest version (2.9.9-3).
libsquashfuse0 is already the newest version (0.1.103-2).
squashfuse is already the newest version (0.1.103-2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 17 not upgraded.
```

Comment: I think you should reinstall `snapd`

Comment: have you checked this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/315063/mount-wrong-fs-type-bad-option-bad-superblock ?

Comment: What kernel version do you have?

Comment: @TheDark_Command since it's a `loop` that answer doesn't apply my case

`sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/loop23
mke2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
mkfs.ext4: Device size reported to be zero.  Invalid partition specified, or
 partition table wasn't reread after running fdisk, due to
 a modified partition being busy and in use.  You may need to reboot
 to re-read your partition table.`

@sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio my linux kernel is: 5.8.0-50-generic

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing some required packages from your system.

Try installing required packages to handle squash file system like so:

```
sudo apt install squashfs-tools squashfuse fuse
```

Then reinstall `snapd` like so:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall snapd
```

Then reboot your system.

Comment: I think the problem is really `wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop23,` as error indicates because I have all those packages. I've updated the question.

Comment: @UchihaItachi Have you reinstalled `snapd` then rebooted your machine? … Snap loops are read only and get recreated after each boot… So usual disk checks and terminology don’t apply to them the way you think

Comment: Yes I reinstalled many times but still same error.

Comment: Any update in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62882262/2707864), which was useful for quite a few, you can try

```
sudo apt-get install libsquashfuse0 squashfuse fuse 
sudo apt-get install --reinstall snapd
```

You might need to reboot.

As per some reports, a kernel update *might* also be sufficient, YMMV.

**Related**

1. [system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs image using "squashfs - mount failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1241781/system-does-not-fully-support-snapd-cannot-mount-squashfs-image-using-squashfs) (I am not sure this is included in your "all other similar question").
2. https://forum.radxa.com/t/snap-on-xubuntu/511
3. https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/issues/362
4. https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapd/+bug/1859703

Comment: I've updated the question with your suggestion. That post that you linked one of the thing I was trying to install squashfs but it was already the newest version.

Comment: `libsquashfuse0` is a dependency  for `squashfuse` … It’s enough to install `squashfuse`… Why are you installing both?… Please see https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/squashfuse