# The system not support snapd in Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: snap

```
sudo snap install hello-world
[sudo] password for noax: 
error: system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount
       squashfs image using "squashfs": ----- mount:
       /tmp/syscheck-mountpoint-1214103833: wrong fs type,
       bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0, missing codepage
       or helper program, or other error.

       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.

   -----
```

> noax@noax:~$ uname -a Linux noax 6.2.0-20-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP
> PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Apr  6 07:48:48 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64
> GNU/Linux

dmseg red lines:

> 0.270982] SELinux: CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_CHECKREQPROT_VALUE is non-zero.  This is deprecated and will be rejected in a future kernel
> release. [    0.270999] SELinux:
> https://github.com/SELinuxProject/selinux-kernel/wiki/DEPRECATE-checkreqprot
>
> [    0.502251] ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer]
> (****ptrval****) (20221020/exresop-66) [    0.502251] ACPI Error:
> AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store]
> (20221020/dswexec-433)
>
> [    0.502251] ACPI Error: Aborting method _PR.CPU0._PDC due to
> previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE) (20221020/psparse-529)
>
> 3.498852] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
>
> 15.063000] usb 3-6: 1:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x1
>
> 20.189003] usb 3-6: 1:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x1

Comment: Did you check what is logged into dmesg, as suggest in the output you posted? Please add the lines in dmesg related to your problem.

Comment: I'd bet you're running a non-standard kernel. What's the output of `uname -a`?

Comment: I try to put the output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs image using "squashfs - mount failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1241781/system-does-not-fully-support-snapd-cannot-mount-squashfs-image-using-squashfs)

Comment: that didnt work for me.