# error: system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs image using "squashfs": exec: "mount": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: usb, permissions, mount, wubi

```
Error: Snapd Unable to Mount Squashfs Image with 'mount' Executable Not Found
```

I encountered an error while using Snap on my Ubuntu system. The error message states that the system does not fully support Snapd due to the inability to mount a squashfs image. The specific issue is the absence of the 'mount' executable in the system's PATH. Despite reinstalling the 'mount' package and verifying its integrity, the problem persists. I kindly request assistance in resolving this issue to ensure proper functionality of Snap on my Ubuntu system.

example - `sudo snap refresh`:

```
error: system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs image using "squashfs": exec:
       "mount": executable file not found in $PATH
```

Comment: Basic starting details are what OS/release you're using, you mention Ubuntu, but gave no clues as to what product (Server? Desktop? Core? etc) or what release of that *unstated* product...  Providing clear *pastes* of your command & error message would also be helpful  (not just explaining around it)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs image using "squashfs - mount failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1241781/system-does-not-fully-support-snapd-cannot-mount-squashfs-image-using-squashfs)

Comment: Please add the output of `type -a mount`