# Not able to start/launch firefox browser

Tags: firefox

```
cssdesk@JF03CLSSU1026:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS"
cssdesk@JF03CLSSU1026:~$ uname -a
Linux JF03CLSSU1026 6.4.0-rc4 #4 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Aug 28 22:32:12 PDT 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


The following NEW packages will be installed:
  firefox
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/72.3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 261 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 264866 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../firefox_1%3a1snap1-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
=> Installing the firefox snap
==> Checking connectivity with the snap store
==> Installing the firefox snap
error: system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs image using "squashfs": mount:
       /tmp/syscheck-mountpoint-1104631282: unknown filesystem type 'squashfs'.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/firefox_1%3a1snap1-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new firefox package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/firefox_1%3a1snap1-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: <pre>~$ sudo snap refresh
error: system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs image using "squashfs": mount:
       /tmp/syscheck-mountpoint-819084190: unknown filesystem type 'squashfs'. </pre>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs image using "squashfs - mount failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1241781/system-does-not-fully-support-snapd-cannot-mount-squashfs-image-using-squashfs)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install it from its original packages
First of all, download Firefox from the official website:

Open a terminal

Run on it

```
 cd ~/Downloads
 wget https://archive.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/119.0.1/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-119.0.1.tar.bz2
```

Once the file has been downloaded, it can be located in the 'Downloads' folder.

Extract the file using the following command in that terminal:

```
  tar -xjf firefox-119.0.1.tar.bz2
```

We should now have an extracted folder called 'firefox'.

We need to move the folder to '/opt' with the following command:

```
  sudo mv firefox /opt
```

Now, we will create a link to launch the web browser from the terminal.

Run the following command to create the link to Firefox

```
 sudo ln -s /opt/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox
```

Create a launcher on your desktop, dock, etc.

Comment: Thx.. this steps are working.